# how to monitor db audio loudness with ios?

Tags: ios, audio

I want to write a simple app to monitor audio loudness (in db offcourse) through iphone microphone. My question is: which framework do I need to implement that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try [AVAudioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder), specifically the section `Using Audio Level Metering`.